# Maximum execution time não funciona?

Tags: php, laravel

Preciso que minha aplicação pare, acuse erro, "Maximum execution time of 5 seconds exceeded" seria o ideal, desde que o tempo seja superior a 5 segundos por exemplo. Pesquisando aqui mesmo na comunidade encontrei algumas soluções, porém não está surtindo efeito. Existe alguma outra configuração que possa bloquear isso?

Segue o código:

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\Domain\Eventos;

ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);
set_time_limit(5);
```

No caso, estou processando um arquivo e ele processa em cerca de 20 segundos, porém, mesmo com o limitado setado ali, ele não dá timeout.

OBS: não tenho acesso ao php.ini

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Onde vc está colocando esse ini_set?

Comment: Na classe que estou rodando, no caso é a classe que processa o arquivo.

Comment: tenta com a função sleep do php => sleep(5);

Comment: Certo, mas com o sleep, ele vai parar por 5 segundos e depois volta, eu preciso é que a aplicação realmente de erro se passar do tempo informado. No meu caso, é que se levar mais do que 5 segundos, é porque há algo muito errado, entende?

Comment: Depende de onde nessa classe que vc tá aplicando, pois se vc usar apenas um método dela ela não vai nem ver esse ini_set. Ou vc adiciona ao construtor ou no corpo do método

Comment: Sim, eu chamo direto um método de fora, no caso não adiciono o construtor não. Neste caso, existe uma outra alternativa p/ setar esse cara?

Comment: Entendi, veja se esse link te ajuda ! https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded?page=1

Comment: Ok, vou tentar, mas aqui da empresa bloqueia o cadastro. De qualquer forma obrigado.
Vou continuar pesquisando também.

Comment: Nao sei muito bem qual o motivo final você pretende atingir, mas caso seja viavel poderia utilizar o Symfony Process (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) para executar o script como um processo separado e definir um timeout nele.

Comment: Pedro, seria o ideal, mas o "prazo" não permite, o caminho mais rápido que encontrei foi esse.. Porém, por hora sem sucesso.. :(

Answer (score 2):

O `ini_set`, segundo a própria [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ini-set.php)

> Define um novo valor para a opção de configuração indicada. A opção de configuração irá manter o novo valor durante a execução do script e será restaurado ao final da execução do script.

Ou seja, ao executar um script, se estiver definido a diretiva `ini_set`, ele irá alterar **temporariamente** o valor definido e assim que terminar a execução o mesmo irá voltar ao valor inicial. então, vc precisa usa-lo ao iniciar a execuçaõ de um script.

Suponhamos a seguinte rota no laravel

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Na controller eu devo definir o `ini_set` dessa forma

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    class HomeController extends Controller
    {
        public function index() {
            ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);
            /* ... */
        } 
    }
```

ao chamar o método `index` o valor de `max_execution_time` será alterado.
Ou alterar esse valor através do `construtor`

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    class HomeController extends Controller
    {

        public function __construct() {
            ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);
        }

        public function index() {
            /* ... */
        } 
    }
```

dessa forma a chamada de **qualquer método** da `HomeController` irá alterar o valor de `max_execution_time`.

Comment: Eu fiz exatamente desta forma (a do construtor) e o script continua por mais tempo.. Ainda estou investigando.